# Use a loop to draw plot in R

Tags: r

I'm just wondering how I can use a loop to go through some models and draw graphs for them?

I've got lots of mixture models by age groups, with each age group I've fitted 2, 3, 4, 5 component models. I've named them using the following method:

```
  ag1.mix2
  ag1.mix3
  ag1.mix4
  ag1.mix5
  ag2.mix2
  ag2.mix3
  ag2.mix4
  ag2.mix5
```

and so on (ag1 = age group 1; mix2 = 2 mixture components).

Now, I'm trying to draw graphs for each of these models, I tried to simplify the codes by using something like:

```
for(i in 1:11) {
  emf(paste("Mixture Components by Age Group ", i, ".emf"))
  par(mfrow = c(2, 2), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0))
  for(j in 2:5) {
    plot(cat("ag", i, ".mix", j, sep = "", "\n"), which = 2, las = 1, breaks = 100, 
         main2 = paste(j, "components"))    
  }
  title(main = paste("Age Group", agegp[i]), outer = TRUE)
  dev.off()
}
```

However, it didn't quite work and R complains:

```
 Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

If I do it like:

```
plot(ag1.mix2, which = 2, las = 1, breaks = 100, main2 = "2 Comonents")
```

Then it works fine. However, with 4x11 models to go through, I'm hoping that I can use a loop!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Kevin

PS -- the mixture models were fitted using the mixtools package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `get`

like

```
for(j in 2:5) {
data_to_plot=get(paste0("ag", i, ".mix", j ))
    plot(data_to_plot, which = 2, las = 1, breaks = 100, 
         main2 = paste(j, "components"))    
  }
```

small working example :

```
data1=1:10
data2=2:20

for (i in 1:2){
  png(paste0("plot_",i,".png"))
  data_to_plot=get(paste0("data", i))
  plot(data_to_plot)
  dev.off()
}
```